# What are the major vulnerabilities of Windows 2003 + Apache?

Tags: security

I am searching for a host for a new commercial website. Among other things, I'd like to know what the various OS - Webserver combinations have in terms of vulnerabilities. What are the vulnerabilities of Windows 2003 + Apache?

Comment: Or an anti-phishing how-to. It's hard to tell, isn't it? :)

Answer (score 1):

You could look here: http://httpd.apache.org/security/vulnerabilities_20.html

As for the windows side, it's windows. There are going to be vulnerabilities. Just stay up to date with service packs and patches, and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87393/what-are-the-major-vulnerabilities-of-windows-2003-iis), I could check out the [CERT Database](http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/).